# Is there any evidence of the miracles of Tulsidas?

Tags: middle-ages, india, mughals

Several miracles are attributed to the great medieval poet and philosopher [Tulsidas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulsidas), among them reviving the dead, and one of the ones that most caught my attention was his arrest by Emperor Akbar. Tulsidas was released from the jail by an army of angry monkeys. Is there any evidence of this particular event, that Tulsidas was arrested by Akbar and then released by monkeys? Undoubtedly, an event of such magnitude must have been documented by the sources of the time, especially those of the Mughal government.

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia article on [Tulsidas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulsidas#Attributed_miracles)? Does that help at all?

Comment: @LarsBosteen: Wikipedia says it, I believe it, that settles it. ;-)

Comment: Interesting — that Wikipedia article is one of the worst I've seen for failing to consistently qualify legend! It as much as says he reincarnated Valmiki, for example. Unfortunately, it'll be hard to outdo Wikipedia's sources, the "groups of biographers", without access to scholars with a neutral, skeptical approach.

Comment: Well, if you had concrete evidence they would not be miracles :) Instead, they would be a proof that supernatural things exist. I vote to close this as opinion based .